Liquibase and Gradle in
I have setup liquibase in a Gradle convention plugin like
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      changelogFile "../liquibaseMaster.xml"
      driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      url "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=acuni;queryTimeout=120;lockTimeout=15000;trustServerCertificate=true"
      username "user" 
      password "test" 
      outputFile "./build/liquibase/output-file.txt"
    }
  }
}

liquibaseMaster.xml looks like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

  <includeAll path="./cfg/liquibase/"/>
</databaseChangeLog>

When I run liquibase commands from subprojects, everything works fine. E. g. subproject subA executes liquibase's update command from directory root/subA. ./cfg/liquibase/ from liquibaseMaster.xml resolves to ./subA/cfg/liquibase/.
When I run the update command from root, ./cfg/liquibase/ resolves to ./cfg/liquibase/, but that directory does not exist. Any idea how to solve this?

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.
